# Illegal Mix Of Collations While Comparing Datetime with String

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures, collation, sql-like

I have created a MYSQL stored procedure that searches all columns of a table (parameter 1) to find if any of them contains a string (parameter 2). The problem is that when I compare a datetime column with a string that contains greek characters I get the following error:

**SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_datetime LIKE '%ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΑ%';**
*Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'*

The execution of the query is successful when I use latin characters. I know how to avoid checking columns based on their datatype, however I really want to be able to search for datetime strings as well. I use MySQL 5.5.24. The collation of the database is utf8_general_ci and the collation of the server is latin1_swedish_ci. I have tried the command SET NAMES utf8 before the query, with no luck though. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: this might provide some help .
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38988033/2155377

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a problem with similar query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_date LIKE '%2012-01%';
```

The result was an "Illegal mix of collations" error.

Using simply [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function helped:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(some_date, '%Y-%m-%d') LIKE '%2012-01%';
```

Comment: actually this is a workaround for a mysql bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61034