# Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like' while searching with Ignited-Datatables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, datatable

I have successfully implemented Ignited-Datatables. However, while searching with database when typing "non-latin" characters like "İ,ş,ğ,.."

`POST http://vproject.dev/module/user/ign_listing 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Details are:

```
Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like' while searching
... (u.id_user LIKE '%Ä°%' OR u.first_name LIKE '%Ä°%' OR u.last_name LIKE '%Ä°%' OR ue.email LIKE '%Ä°%' OR u.last_login LIKE '%Ä°%' ) ...
```

`%Ä°%` part changes according to the non-latin character you typed.

Any idea for solving this?

Comment: One option is to use `convert(datefield using utf-8)`...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It seems it is DATETIME fields that causes the problem.

```
.. ue.last_login '%ayşenur%'
```

gives error for `Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'`. When I remove `LIKE` partials `DATETIME` fields, there are no error any more. I hope this helps.

Comment: Merhaba. did you fix this issue without removing DATETIME?

Comment: No, LIKE and DATETIME incompitablity is a MySQL problem. Hope to be fixed in later versions.

Comment: As I understand, the problem is on JSON UNICODE DECODES. So, in PHP 5.4 it should work. Did you try it at the latest PHP version?

Comment: @RiKo You may be right. The question is one year old, so I did not try with the latest version. Let me and community know if you try and make it work. Thanks

Comment: @RiKo Did you try with the latest version?

Comment: here's a documented mysql bug, for reference: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61034

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```sql
u.id_user LIKE '%Ä°%' OR ... OR ... '%Ä°%' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Refer to [**MySQL Unicode Character Sets**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)

Also you can refer to [**MySQL _bin and binary Collations**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-binary-collations.html) for more information on `utf8_bin`:

> Nonbinary strings (as stored in the CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT data
>   types) have a character set and collation. A given character set can
>   have several collations, each of which defines a particular sorting
>   and comparison order for the characters in the set. One of these is
>   the binary collation for the character set, indicated by a _bin suffix
>   in the collation name. For example, latin1 and utf8 have binary
>   collations named latin1_bin and utf8_bin.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge but it didn't work. I think it is something about how the library handles the post data.

Comment: Why don't you try `var_dump($this->input->post());` in your controller to see exactly what CI is doing to those chars.

Comment: I did. It is where the problem is. I am stacked with this, how come post is not utf-8?

Comment: The POST seems UTF-8, it is okay. Something wrong with Ignited-Datatables_

Comment: Further reference [link] (https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/issues/38)

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little bit old. 
Finally I find a solution change "LIKE " TO "LIKE binary "

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem in Datatable search ssp.class.php
i solved by converting to UTF8 like :

```
CONVERT(`user_datetime` USING utf8)
```

**fix in ssp.class.php:**

```
$globalSearch[] = "CONVERT(`".$column['db']."` USING utf8) LIKE ".$binding;
```

My final code was :

```
static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
{
    $globalSearch = array();
    $columnSearch = array();
    $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );
 
    if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
        $str = $request['search']['value'];
 
        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
            $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
            $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];
 
            if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $globalSearch[] = "CONVERT(`".$column['db']."` USING utf8) LIKE ".$binding;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i know that this is far too late, but, here my workaround.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(some_date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS some_date FROM some_table)tb1
WHERE some_date LIKE '% $some_variable %'
```

datetime/date column gives error for Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like', therefore, by converting it, as another table entity, previous column type will be replace with varchar type.

also, make sure to convert any column before convert it to temporary table, to make matching process more easier.

Comment: Not in a position to test it but I liked the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar error when `LIKE` was applied to the `DateTime` column.
So now, instead of using simple `date_col LIKE '2019%'` I use `CAST(date_col AS CHAR) LIKE '2019%'`.

The solution was found on the official [MySQL bugs website](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38915).