# Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like' Error Message

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I am using codeigniter with datatables , and when i put any Arabic letter on search input box i have Error message " Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'" How to fix that 
Thanks

Comment: make sure the input  you are matching with the database must be `utf8_general_ci` or use `COLLATE` in your where clause

Comment: I am using utf8_general_ci in database , what the right way to use COLLATE in where clause



$this->db->select('*');

   $this->db->from('training');
   $this->db->join('unversity', 'unversity.UnVerId = training.university');
$this->db->join('major', 'major.DeptID = training.major');
$this->db->join('cualification', 'cualification.CerID = training.cualification');

Comment: and  works fine in localhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like' while searching with Ignited-Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629094/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-like-while-searching-with-ignited-data)