# LARAVEL 5.4 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1271 on godaddy server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, collation

I'm encounter an error when i do search the chinese character in laravel, it gave me General error: 1271,

here is my code:

```
$sales_record = SalesRecord::select(DB::raw('sales_records.id as id, sales_records.amount as amount, clients.name as name, sales_records.created_at as created_at, sales_records.updated_at as updated_at '))
                                  ->join('clients', 'sales_records.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
                                  ->Where('sales_records.amount', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                                  ->orWhere('clients.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                                  ->orWhere('sales_records.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                                  ->orWhere('sales_records.updated_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                                  ->orderBy('sales_records.created_at', 'DESC')
                                  ->paginate(10);
```

And here is the error[image: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1271 Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like']

And this error only appear on my godaddy share hosting, there is no error in my localhost.

Anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: Check the collation for all joined tables. It should be the same.

Comment: What version of MySQL is running on your hosting?

Comment: @apokryfos the collation of table is utf8mb4_unicode_ci, and the database is utf1_general_ci

Comment: @benJ mysql version is 5.6

Comment: @BluYcw is that the collation of all tables that are joined?

Comment: @apokryfos sorry, i'm not sure what you mean join the collation of table, but i use "join" keyword in my sql to join 2 table, if not, can you tell me how to join the collation of the table? thank you

Comment: My question is is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` the collation of `sales_records` **and** `clients` ?

Comment: @apokryfos yes， both are the same

Comment: Check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#configuration make sure your `charset` is `utf8mb4` and your collation matches `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` in your configuration.

Comment: @apokryfos the charset and collation is match

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629094/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-like-while-searching-with-ignited-data . It may be an issue with using LIKE and a `DATETIME` field in some MySQL versions.

Comment: @apokryfos its working now, i remove the like statement that compare with timestamp then it work, thanks for help

Comment: What client are you using for entering the Chinese literals?